# c# tabControl background color

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I need some help with tabControl background color (the open space to the right of the tabs)

Below is my code and I have managed to change the tabControl's background color to white. How will I be able to change the background color of the tab that is not selected?

```
 Image cross = imageList1.Images[0];

        int xWidth = cross.Width;

        TabPage tp = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

        Size size = tabControl1.ItemSize;

        Font fntTab;
        Brush bshBack;
        Brush bshFore;

        string tabName = this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text;

        string tabName2 = this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text;            

        if (e.Index == this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            fntTab = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular);
            bshBack = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds, Color.White, Color.FromName(theme), System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);

            Brush tabBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromName("Black"));

            bshFore = tabBrush;

            SolidBrush fillbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromName("White"));

            Rectangle lasttabrect = tabControl1.GetTabRect(this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1);
            Rectangle background = new Rectangle();
            background.Location = new Point(lasttabrect.Left, 0);

            background.Size = new Size(tabControl1.Right - background.Left, tabControl1.Height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(fillbrush, background);

            this.Text = title + " - " + tabName2;
            filename_status_label.Text = tabName;               
        }
        else
        {
            fntTab = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular);

            bshBack = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            bshFore = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);               
        }
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab != null)
        {
            formtitle = tabName2;

            StringFormat sftTab = new StringFormat();
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bshBack, e.Bounds);
            Rectangle recTab = e.Bounds;
            recTab = new Rectangle(recTab.X + 5, recTab.Y + 4, recTab.Width, recTab.Height - 4);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(formtitle, fntTab, bshFore, recTab, sftTab);

            currentCrossRect = new Rectangle(
            e.Bounds.Left + size.Width - 22, 3, xWidth, xWidth);

            cross1or2 = cross;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(cross1or2, currentCrossRect.X - 2, currentCrossRect.Y + 2);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You are using white in both if-blocks.  I have no idea what those other circles are supposed to mean.

Comment: The first white is for the tabControl background (space right of the tabs). The second white is for the background color of the unselected tab (text and cross). I'm trying to cover the outside of the tab

Comment: You mean like the border-like areas?

Comment: That is correct yes. The yellow circles indicates where the background is still the default color of the tabControl that is not white